# How to join multiple processes in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, process

So I've made a small c++ binary to connect to do a command on a server to stress test it, so i started working on the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((  i = 0 ;  i <= 15;  i++  ))
do
   ./mycppbinary test 1 &
done
```

Now, I also happen to want to time how long all the processes take to execute. I suppose I'll have to do a time command on each of these processes?

Is it possible to join those processes, as if they're a thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't join them, you `wait` on them. At lest in [bash](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2008/06/bash-wait-command.html), and probably other shells with job control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bash `fg` command to bring the last background process back into the foreground.  Do it in another loop to catch them all, though some may complete before this causing you to get an error about no such process.  You're not joining processes, they aren't threads, they each have their own pid and unique memory space.

Answer (score 0):

**1st, make the script last the same as all its children**

The script you propose will die *before* the processes finish, due to the fact that you are launching them on the background. If you don't want this to happen, you can do as many `wait`s as needed (as Keith suggested).

**2nd, time the script**

Then, you can time your script and that will give you the total execution time, as you requested.

Answer (score -1):

You can time your shell script, that will give you the total execution time.